# How to set UIImageView frame in ViewController for Universal App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, ios6

For a Universal App, how do I set the UIImageView frame in the ViewController?

```
UIView *baseView = [[UIView alloc] init];

[self.view addSubview:baseView];

// Displays UIImageView

UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc]
                        initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tool.png"]];
[baseView addSubview:myImage];
```

When I run app it shows black screen. So i guess I have to set a frame for it.

Comment: what do you mean how to set the frame?  just set it.  but do you mean how to account for different resolutions?  Get the screen size like this `CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];` and use those values to properly position and size your views.

Comment: Thanks for help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You kinda answered your own question - yes you have to set a frame for it.
You may want to try:

```
UIView *baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:baseView];

// Displays UIImageView

UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc]
                    initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tool.png"]];
myImage.frame = baseView.bounds;
[baseView addSubview:myImage];
```

You could also set the autoresizingmask for baseView and myImage so that as self.view's frame changes, so do these two views.

Also, just in case you aren't using ARC - don't forget to autorelease these views before leaving this method.

Comment: Thanks for help. Appreciate it.